# Touchpad unresponsive on resume from sleep on Debian 8

Tags: suspend, touchpad, hibernate

I installed Debian a few weeks ago on my laptop.

When I close the lid and re open it, my touchpad does not respond. If I connect a usb mouse it works great but the touchpad does not. I tried to create `/etc/pm/sleep.d/00_trackpad`:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
suspend|hibernate)
modprobe -r psmouse ;;
resume|thaw)
modprobe psmouse ;;
synclient TouchpadOff=0 ;;
esac
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
resume)
DISPLAY=:0.0 su USER -c '/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0' ;;
esac
```

But neither works.

Computer : Asus 455L

OS :Debian GNU/Linux 8(Jessie) 64 bit. Gnome v 3014.1